# AutoID column for a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was asked by my manager to add an `AutoID` column to the table `UserTracking`, so that all the existing entries could be populated with a value, and for this to be in the same order as the `CreateDate` field (i.e. `ID` 1 is in the earliest entry).

I did this:

```
alter table dbo.UserTracking add  AutoID bigint NULL
go

update dbo.UserTracking
set AutoId=AutoId.AutoId
from dbo.UserTracking as ut
join 
    (
      select  CreateDate,row_number() over (order by CreateDate) as AutoId
      from UserTracking
    ) as AutoId
on ut.CreateDate=AutoId.CreateDate
go

create index IDX__UserTracking__AutoId on dbo.UserTracking (AutoId)  
go
```

BUT I was told that we need the `AutoID` column to be an actual auto `ID` (so that it has automatic new values on record insert) and it should be called `ID` to be consistent with other tables.

From performance point of view it would be perfect if the new `ID (INT)` column is our primary key but it can be hard to do. For now we need the auto `ID` with an index on it.

I'm not entirely sure how to do it myself and I wouldn't want to mess it up. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

Drop the existing column (AutoID) , you cannot make an existing column an Identity column.

Just add another column and make it Identity column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserTracking 
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
GO
```

It will populates the column itself you don't have to do anything .

Comment: Thank you M.Ali! It appears so obvious now that you pointed it out.

Comment: Be aware that the ID for existing rows will not necessarily be correlated with CreateDate.  If you need to backfill in order with a new identity column, you'll need to use `SELECT INTO...ORDER BY CreateDate`.